# Find $\theta$ if a cubic equation has $3$ distinct roots?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to find $\theta$ ,if the equation $$\tan (\theta)x^3+\tan (2\theta)x^2+\cot (2\theta)x+\cot (\theta)=0 $$ have $\bf 3$ distinct roots ?
I got stuck on this problem ,I f you can give an idea I will be appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

The discriminant of cubic $$\tan (\theta)x^3+\tan (2\theta)x^2+\cot (2\theta)x+\cot (\theta)=0$$
is (easily computed because the products between some coefficients are 1):
$$\Delta = -8 - 4 \cot^3(2 x) \tan(x) - 4 \cot(x)\tan^3(2 x) $$
Hence $$\Delta = 0 \implies \tan x \cot^3 (2x) = -1 \implies \tan x =  - \frac{{8{{\tan }^3}x}}{{{{(1 - {{\tan }^2}x)}^3}}}$$
You can solve the latter equation easily (it can be reduced into a cubic with rational root). The answer is (assuming real):
$$\tan x = \pm \sqrt{2+\sqrt{5}}$$

The cubic has **distinct roots** iff $\Delta \neq 0$, **distinct real roots** iff $\Delta > 0$